# Apache Nifi Install not working with java 8 (Launched Apache NiFi but could not determined the Process ID)

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry, apache-nifi-toolkit

I was trying to run apache nifi in windows. I am seeing error.

./run-nifi.bat
2022-12-08 13:00:32,267 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...
2022-12-08 13:00:32,267 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0
2022-12-08 13:00:32,268 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341\bin\java.exe -classpath C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\conf;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\jetty-schemas-5.2.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-api-1.18.0.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-framework-api-1.18.0.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-nar-utils-1.18.0.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-properties-1.18.0.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-property-utils-1.18.0.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-runtime-1.18.0.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-server-api-1.18.0.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-stateless-api-1.18.0.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-stateless-bootstrap-1.18.0.jar;C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Dcurator-log-only-first-connection-issue-as-error-level=true -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dzookeeper.admin.enableServer=false -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -Dnifi.properties.file.path=C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0.\conf\nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=54997 -Dapp=NiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=C:\Users\Salik\Desktop\NIFI-1~1.0\bin..\logs org.apache.nifi.NiFi
2022-12-08 13:00:32,273 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to determine Process ID from [java.lang.ProcessImpl]: java.lang.Process.pid()
2022-12-08 13:00:32,273 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi but could not determined the Process ID

Uninstalling java JDK, Reinstall I tried setting up java home and bin.

Comment: What version of Windows? Also does the user running the NiFi process have permissions to get Process IDs from the operating system?

Answer (score 1):

I had came across the same situation, after runnig .bat file that launches Nifi, it simply did not start and the cmd returned to its initial state.

[This solution](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Apache-Nifi-is-not-starting-up/m-p/231032) helped. Try to clear all folders with '*_repository' name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, it also happens to me.

1. First uninstall JDK 1.8
2. Install JDK 1.14
3. set the environment variable for java.
4. Run again the run-nifi bat file.

Your problem will be resolved.